# CSS 3D vertical Flip Effect animation doesn't look right

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to achieve this style of vertical flip effect https://codepen.io/kanishkkunal/pen/wgEBgX

**SCSS at the link above converted to CSS:**

```
a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #222;
}
a.flip-animate {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
a.flip-animate span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
a.flip-animate span:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  transition: color 0.3s;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  text-align: center;
}
a.flip-animate:hover span, a.flip-animate:focus span {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
}
a.flip-animate:hover span:before, a.flip-animate:focus span:before {
  color: #d24936;
}
```

But using two divs like in this flip effect https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

I've been trying to combine them in a jsfiddle, but I can't seem to get the animation looking quite right. While the codepen effect looks like it's turning on a 3D block, mine just looks like 
 two words turning turning independently. https://jsfiddle.net/gibsonion/jskmp8v2/58/

Comment: The white word looks okay. The yellow word is rotating around its center and not around the bottom edge.

Comment: Yes, can you help? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.